# Pyspark forward and backward fill within column level

Tags: pyspark, imputation

I try to fill missing data in a pyspark dataframe. The pyspark dataframe looks as such:

```
+---------+---------+-------------------+----+
| latitude|longitude|      timestamplast|name|
+---------+---------+-------------------+----+
|         | 4.905615|2019-08-01 00:00:00|   1|
|51.819645|         |2019-08-01 00:00:00|   1|
| 51.81964| 4.961713|2019-08-01 00:00:00|   2|
|         |         |2019-08-01 00:00:00|   3|
| 51.82918| 4.911187|                   |   3|
| 51.82385| 4.901488|2019-08-01 00:00:03|   5|
+---------+---------+-------------------+----+
```

Within the column "name" I want to either forward fill or backward fill (whichever is necessary) to fill only "latitude" and "longitude" ("timestamplast" should not be filled). How do I do this?

Output will be:

```
+---------+---------+-------------------+----+
| latitude|longitude|      timestamplast|name|
+---------+---------+-------------------+----+
|51.819645| 4.905615|2019-08-01 00:00:00|   1|
|51.819645| 4.905615|2019-08-01 00:00:00|   1|
| 51.81964| 4.961713|2019-08-01 00:00:00|   2|
| 51.82918| 4.911187|2019-08-01 00:00:00|   3|
| 51.82918| 4.911187|                   |   3|
| 51.82385| 4.901488|2019-08-01 00:00:03|   5|
+---------+---------+-------------------+----+
```

In Pandas this would be done as such:

```
df = df.groupby("name")['longitude','latitude'].apply(lambda x : x.ffill().bfill())
```

How would this be done in Pyspark?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest you use the following two Window Specs:

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
w1 = Window.partitionBy('name').orderBy('timestamplast')
w2 = w1.rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing)
```

**Where:**

1. **w1** is the regular WinSpec we use to calculate the forward-fill which is the same as the following:

   ```
   w1 = Window.partitionBy('name').orderBy('timestamplast').rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding,0)
   ```

   see the following note from the [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Window) for default window frames:

   > **Note:** When ordering is not defined, an unbounded window frame (rowFrame, unboundedPreceding, unboundedFollowing) is used by default. When ordering is defined, a growing window frame (rangeFrame, unboundedPreceding, currentRow) is used by default.
2. after `ffill`, we only need to fix the null values at the very front if exists, so we can use a fixed Window frame(Between Window.unboundedPreceding and Window.unboundedFollowing), this is more efficient than using a running Window frame since it requires only one aggregate, see [SPARK-8638](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-8638)

Then the *x.ffill().bfill()* can be handled by using [coalesce](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.coalesce) + [last](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.last) + [first](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.first) based on the above two WindowSpecs:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import coalesce, last, first

df.withColumn('latitude_new', coalesce(last('latitude',True).over(w1), first('latitude',True).over(w2))) \
  .select('name','timestamplast', 'latitude','latitude_new') \
  .show()
+----+-------------------+---------+------------+
|name|      timestamplast| latitude|latitude_new|
+----+-------------------+---------+------------+
|   1|2019-08-01 00:00:00|     null|   51.819645|
|   1|2019-08-01 00:00:01|     null|   51.819645|
|   1|2019-08-01 00:00:02|51.819645|   51.819645|
|   1|2019-08-01 00:00:03| 51.81964|    51.81964|
|   1|2019-08-01 00:00:04|     null|    51.81964|
|   1|2019-08-01 00:00:05|     null|    51.81964|
|   1|2019-08-01 00:00:06|     null|    51.81964|
|   1|2019-08-01 00:00:07| 51.82385|    51.82385|
+----+-------------------+---------+------------+
```

**Edit:** to process (ffill+bfill) on multiple columns, use a list comprehension:

```
cols = ['latitude', 'longitude']
df_new = df.select([ c for c in df.columns if c not in cols ] + [ coalesce(last(c,True).over(w1), first(c,True).over(w2)).alias(c) for c in cols ])
```

Comment: How would I do this when I also want to ffill, bfill the column "longitude too" ? Repeat the procedure? In my actual project I want to fill over many columns, except those not specified.

Comment: @Jeroen, you can use a list comprehension, see the updated post.

Comment: Taking the `first` in an `unbounded` window wouldn't replace all values of the column with the first (non-null) value?

Answer (score 2):

I got a working solution for either forward or backward fill of one target name "longitude". I guess I could repeat the procedure for also "latitude" and then again for backward fill. Is there a more efficient way?

```
window = Window.partitionBy('name')\
               .orderBy('timestamplast')\
               .rowsBetween(-sys.maxsize, 0) # this is for forward fill  
               # .rowsBetween(0,sys.maxsize) # this is for backward fill  

# define the forward-filled column
filled_column = last(df['longitude'], ignorenulls=True).over(window)  # this is for forward fill  
# filled_column = first(df['longitude'], ignorenulls=True).over(window)  # this is for backward fill

df = df.withColumn('mmsi_filled', filled_column) # do the fill
```