# Pyspark get time difference from timestamps within column level

Tags: pyspark, python-datetime

I try to get the time difference "time_d" in seconds of a timestamp within "name" in Pyspark.

```
+-------------------+----+
|      timestamplast|name|
+-------------------+----+
|2019-08-01 00:00:00|   1|
|2019-08-01 00:01:00|   1|
|2019-08-01 00:01:15|   1|
|2019-08-01 03:00:00|   2|
|2019-08-01 04:00:00|   2|
|2019-08-01 00:15:00|   3|
+-------------------+----+
```

Output should look like:

```
+-------------------+----+--------+
|      timestamplast|name| time_d |
+-------------------+----+------- +
|2019-08-01 00:00:00|   1| 0      | 
|2019-08-01 00:01:00|   1| 60     | 
|2019-08-01 00:01:15|   1| 15     |
|2019-08-01 03:00:00|   2| 0      |
|2019-08-01 04:00:00|   2| 3600   |
|2019-08-01 00:15:00|   3| 0      |
+-------------------+----+--------+
```

In Pandas this would be:

```
df['time_d'] = df.groupby("name")['timestamplast'].diff().fillna(pd.Timedelta(0)).dt.total_seconds()
```

How would this be done in Pyspark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a **`lag window function(partitioned by name)`** and then compute the difference using **`timestamp in seconds(unix_timestamp)`**.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

w=Window().partitionBy("name").orderBy(F.col("timestamplast"))
df.withColumn("time_d", F.lag(F.unix_timestamp("timestamplast")).over(w))\
  .withColumn("time_d", F.when(F.col("time_d").isNotNull(), F.unix_timestamp("timestamplast")-F.col("time_d"))\
                         .otherwise(F.lit(0))).orderBy("name","timestamplast").show()

#+-------------------+----+------+
#|      timestamplast|name|time_d|
#+-------------------+----+------+
#|2019-08-01 00:00:00|   1|     0|
#|2019-08-01 00:01:00|   1|    60|
#|2019-08-01 00:01:15|   1|    15|
#|2019-08-01 03:00:00|   2|     0|
#|2019-08-01 04:00:00|   2|  3600|
#|2019-08-01 00:15:00|   3|     0|
#+-------------------+----+------+
```

Comment: Great solution. Do you maybe have an answer for:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61932391/pyspark-forward-and-backward-fill-within-column-level