# Groupby / Merging / Rolling up dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Firstly - I am so lost, I don't even know how to phrase / title my question.

My first dataframe was key value pairs, which I pivoted out with some simple code and it gave me the dataframe which you can see in image 1:

```
df = df.groupBy("ID", "SUBID").pivot("SOURCE", fields).agg(first(F.col("VALUE")))
```

[image]

It sort of has what I want, but I think I need to groupby again or merge or *something* to get my desired result, image 2..

I have tried a few things, but none seem to work. The only one which makes sense to me is I would either need another group by or a self join of some sort?

The result I would like (As I know its all for the same person [ID]) would be something like the below... Same `Name` has been applied across the board, same `surname`, same `Town` etc. Cells that contain values would retain their current values.

[image]

Looking for any advice or duplicate questions please.

Comment: check this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61932391/pyspark-forward-and-backward-fill-within-column-level

Comment: you want to complete with default values ? or with values from another line ? what happen when there are several values already in it ? which one do you choose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a window for the `id` column and then check for all other columns if the values within each window are unique. If so replace the `null` values with this unique value, otherwise replace the `null`s with `###`.

```python
#creating some test data
data=[[1,'abc',None, 'def'],
      [1, None,None, 'ghi'],
      [1, None,'xyz', 'jkl'],
      [1, None,'XYZ', 'mno'],
      [2, '123','456', None],
      [2, None,None, '789']
    ]
df=spark.createDataFrame(data, ["id", "col1", "col2", "col3"])
#+---+----+----+----+
#| id|col1|col2|col3|
#+---+----+----+----+
#|  1| abc|null| def|
#|  1|null|null| ghi|
#|  1|null| xyz| jkl|
#|  1|null| XYZ| mno|
#|  2| 123| 456|null|
#|  2|null|null| 789|
#+---+----+----+----+

w = Window.partitionBy("id")

filled_cols=[F.col("id")] + \
  [F.coalesce(c,
    F.when(F.size(F.collect_set(c).over(w))==1, 
    F.collect_set(c).over(w)[0]).otherwise("###")).alias(c) 
  for c in df.columns if c != "id"]

df.select(filled_cols).show()
#+---+----+----+----+
#| id|col1|col2|col3|
#+---+----+----+----+
#|  1| abc| ###| def|
#|  1| abc| ###| ghi|
#|  1| abc| xyz| jkl|
#|  1| abc| XYZ| mno|
#|  2| 123| 456| 789|
#|  2| 123| 456| 789|
#+---+----+----+----+
```

Comment: This is great - thank you Werner, will play around with it :)